# nginx redirecting a certain site from http to https not working

Tags: nginx

I have following nginx configurations for my docker stack.

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  65000;
}

http {
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    upstream api {
        server api:3000;
    }

    upstream app {
        server app:8000;
    }
   
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name api.atimu.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.atimu.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.atimu.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        gzip on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name app.atimu.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.atimu.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.atimu.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        gzip on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.atimu.com;
        return 301 https://api.atimu.com$request_uri;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.atimu.com;
        return 301 https://app.atimu.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Everything works, except the redirection part. **app** opens on https but, does not open (redirect to HTTPS) on HTTP.
I want **only** (not API) `http://app.atimu.com` to redirect to `https://app.atimu.com`. What am I doing wrong?

Updates:

1. added redirect block for app
2. removed port 80 for app SSL configuration
3. added redirect block for api
4. removed port 80 for api SSL configuration

Result:

1. Able to access both app and API with https
2. Still HTTP not redirecting to https

Comment: You appear to have a duplicate server name error. Have you tested the configuration using `nginx -t`? The first and last `server` blocks both listen on port 80 for the same `server_name`.

Comment: I have commented out port 80 in the second server. My idea is one configuration will listen to app on port 80 and another one will listen on port 443. I tried to follow https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx. How would you do it? can you share your version of the solution?

Comment: It seems that your question is that you do not want `http://api.atimu.com` to redirect to `https://app.atimu.com`? What do you want Nginx to do instead? Redirect to `https://api.atimu.com` or drop the connection?

Comment: @RichardSmith I decied to redirect API to https also. Changed the nginx.conf and added results. please check.

Comment: Be careful using 301 for these redirects - it will tell your browser to redirect in future without checking.  So if you have been testing combinations of this already then it might not be working as you think - any changes you are making might be ignored.  Use 302 until you are happy it is working, or add an `expires` directive to a 301 to force it to re-validate with the server occasionally.

Comment: Also, I would suggest reviewing those proxy buffering parameters - those memory buffers are allocated **per connection**, so for each of the 65000 * CPU potential connections you have configured, that's ... that's a *LOT* of memory!

Comment: You probably need to reset the browser's cache. The last two `server` blocks could be combined into one by using `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: @RichardSmith resetting browser cache worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps(as suggested by @RichardSmith) fixed the issue for me.

1. Either write site-specific redirection rule or generic redirection rule for HTTP to https

```
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.atimu.com;
        return 301 https://api.atimu.com$request_uri;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.atimu.com;
        return 301 https://app.atimu.com$request_uri;
    }
```

or

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

2. Remove HTTP port listener from SSL configuration blocks.

```
  server {
        # liten 80; Remove this line
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name app.atimu.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.atimu.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.atimu.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

        gzip on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

3. Restart nginx, in my case it was dockerized, so I just had to
   restart the stack
4. Clear browser cache. **This is important**, even after completing the above steps it didn't work in my browser because the previous configuration was cached.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have incomplete nginx configuration, please add below block in nginx file, and restart the webserver.

```
server {
if ($host = app.atimu.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

    listen 80;
    server_name app.atimu.com;
return 404;
}
```

Also I would like to know if you have issued the ssl certificate using below command which automaticly creates ssl block for your domain which redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d app.atimu.com
```

Comment: Yes, SSL ins configured properly, I am able to connect with https, it's just that HTTP is not redirecting to https. I will try your code and update you.